# First time on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

Hey I'm learning `ReactJs` these days. As a starter, I don't know which extensions might be useful. I'm working on `VS Code`. By default its giving me these types of syntax errors:
[image]

Can someone recommend me some useful extensions for React on VS Code?

Comment: Maybe some sort of React/JSX plugin; just an idea. Turns out you can find them in VSCode by searching. In any case, SO isn't the place to ask regarding how to set up your environment, and searching the web should be sufficient.

Comment: For Google Chrome extensions, look up `React Developer Tools`.

Comment: The atom editor

Comment: You'll need a React extension for VS Code, but you still have a few syntax errors in your code.

Comment: you should google it first or you should first take some tutorials...

Answer (score 2):

To get started I can recommend these packages:

- React-Native/React/Redux snippets for es6/es7
- Prettier - Code formatter
- ESLint
- Debugger for Chrome

And use React Developer Tools in Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple return statements. Should be:

```
render() {
  return (<div>content</div>)
}
```